# Как поступить с правкой, если все сделанно правильно, но комментарий сделан не на русском языке?

Tags: предложение, правки

Например:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/421176

Совершенно справедливо автор правки добавил тег C#, но комментарий к правке выглядит так:

> "C# question not only wpf tag needed."

В связи с тем, что на данном сайте запрещены вопросы, ответы и комментарии к тем и другим не на русском языке, логично ожидать распространения этого правила и на комментарии к правкам. Причем, такую правку невозможно ни законно исправить (исправление ТОЛЬКО комментария приводит к тому, что движок stackoverflow считает, что правки не было), ни отклонить (нет законной причины отклонения в списке причин). Предлагаю: следует либо считать исправления комментария к правке такой же правкой (что сложнее, но справедливее), либо просто добавить причину отклонения "Комментарий не на русском языке" (проще, но слишком жестко). Это еще хорошо, если комментарий на английском и можно исправить, а представьте, если кто-то прокомментирует на, например, венгерском и случай более сложный, чем добавления тега.

Comment: Я думаю принимать. Какая разница правка хорошая и все ,а коментарий это так, условно. **Disclaimer**:Это моя правка ;)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica хорошо, в данном случае приму, но в общим случает, по моему скромному мнению, важно само содержимое комментария для понимания необходимости правки (в более сложных случаях)

Answer (score 4):

Комментарий к правке нельзя "Исправить" - такой функции нет на сайте. Можно, теоретически, отклонить правку и применить ее же самому, переведя комментарий и добавив приписку "основано на правке пользователя ..." (с целью соблюдения лицензии). Но наиболее целесообразно просто принять правку, если ее смысл самоочевиден и не требует пояснений (как в случае добавления метки [c#] в вопрос с кодом на C#). В конце концов, для высокореповых пользователей комментарий к правке вообще не обязателен. Если же смысл правки не очевиден без комментария, отклонить с нестандартной причиной, попросив перевести комментарий.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то модераторы могут изменять описание к правке, но проблемы это не решает.